# Which is better Intel Celerdon D 351 3.2Ghz or AMD Athlon 64 3200+

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, intel-celeron

I have two machines, and I want to make one into a media center. No sure which one to pick.

[Here](http://tinyurl.com/amdprocessor) are the specs for the [AMD Athlon 64 3200+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Athlon_64_microprocessors#.22Venice.22_.28E3_.26_E6.2C_90_nm.29), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#.22Prescott-256.22_.2890_nm.29) for the [Intel Celerdon D 351](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#.22Prescott-256.22_.2890_nm.29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Athlon 64 3200+ is the better performer of the two (by a far cry).

**[SuperPi](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36)** (1m calcs): 44 sec vs 71 sec

even the Sempron 3200 (AMDs low cost counterpart to Intel's Celeron series) beats the the Celeron D351 by almost 30% in benchmarks, it certainly is no match for the Athlon with its 512 L2 cache.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, it doesn't really matter. The perfomance difference between the two would be hardly noticeable. Just choose the one that you find has the best motherboard support.

Personally, I would go with a 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, mainly because of the dual cores which could aid in movie playback.

Answer (score 1):

I own an AMD Athlon 64 3000+; it's a very capable CPU. In my opinion, the AMD CPU is way better than the Celeron. Also, I found it's pretty quiet and has no heating problems, which is always important on a media center machine.